# I can't parametrize babel's \foreignlanguage command

Tags: macros, babel

In a document comparing Indo European languages, I try to define some shorthand notations for marking text in different languages, and hyphenating them each correctly. Being a programmer new to LaTeX, I also use cases like this to learn the LaTeX language.

By reducing the code to a minimal working example, the meaning may have been lost. What I try to do, is establish shorthand notations for all the languages that I can pass to **babel**'s `\foreignlanguage` as argument, and encapsulate that into a few different commands that mark up grammatic roles of words in each of these languages.

But this short code still shows the problem well. When I redefine **babel**'s `\foreignlanguage` command to do something visible with it's arguments, this works:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[french,dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{xstring}
\renewcommand{\foreignlanguage}[2]{A: #1 {\small #2} B: {\huge #1} #2}
\newcommand{\said}[2][nl]{
    \foreignlanguage{{\IfStrEqCase{#1}{{fr}{french}}[dutch]}}{\textit{``#2''}}}
\begin{document}
\said{Niets}

\said[fr]{Rien}

\end{document}
```

The result of this is fine:

[image: working example with self-defined "foreignlanguage" command]

At least this proves that my definition `\newcommand{\said}` has a working syntax, for a `\foreignlanguage` command that takes 2 arguments. Now if I comment out the line redefining `\renewcommand{\foreignlanguage}`, so that the original **babel** definition `\foreignlanguage{<language>}{<text>}` comes into force again, then the code stops working. I get a loop of these error messages

- Use of \said doesn't match its definition. \said{Niets}
- Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }. \said{Niets}
- Paragraph ended before \@firstoftwo was complete. \said{Niets}

The log expands on this:

```
! Use of \\said doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.8 \said{Niets}
If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.

! Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.8 \said{Niets}
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \@firstoftwo was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.8 \said{Niets}
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
```

If I comment out the line with

```
\said{Niets}
```

I get the same error messages for the line with

```
\said[fr]{Rien}
```

Probably the stack of errors got full before getting to that second line.

What is the difference between **babel**'s `\foreignlanguage` and my dummy redefinition, that makes the code not work for **babel**'s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately several commands from `xstring` are not fully expandable.  You need to use each case of `\IfStrEqCase` to define a helper macro storing the appropriate value.  Here is one way to do this:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french,dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\expandlangabbr}[2]{\IfStrEqCase{#1}%
  {{fr}{\xdef#2{french}}}%
  [\xdef#2{dutch}]}

\newcommand{\said}[2][nl]{\expandlangabbr{#1}{\mylang}%
  \foreignlanguage{\mylang}{\textit{``#2''}}}

\begin{document}

\said{Niets}

\said[fr]{Rien}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The concept 'expandable' is indeed one that I am still struggling with. Your code works, thanks a lot. But as it concantenates the language shorthand into the name of an additional macro, I guess it would be good to make the default case 'nl' for "dutch" an explicit case:

Comment: I was called away for dinner, and 'comments may only be editted for 5 minutes'.  So I repeat: Your code works, thanks a lot, and though I don't understand it yet, I'll try to find out. For now I can say: after using `\said[fr]`, the command `\show\mylang` displays in the log as `\mylang=macro:->french.`

But as it concantenates the language shorthand into the name of an additional macro, I guess it would be good to make the default case 'nl' for "dutch" an explicit case: `\newcommand{\expandlangabbr}[2]{\IfStrEqCase{#1}%
  {{nl}{\xdef#2{dutch}}{fr}{\xdef#2{french}}}%
  [\xdef#2{dutch}]}`

Comment: Adding the expansion for `nl` is not necessary, it will fall through to the default case anyway.  On the other hand, you could make the default in the helper macro to be some error construct, e.g. `\newcommand{\expandlangabbr}[2]{\IfStrEqCase{#1}% {{nl}{\xdef#2{dutch}}{fr}{\xdef#2{french}}}% [\GenericWarning{expandlangabbr]{Invalid language #1}]}`

Comment: OK, I understand it now. I was not aware that you could use a Tex command like \xdef in Latex too. For other newbees reading this: (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/expandafter) and (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/xdef) are the documentation to read.

Answer (score 5):

You need something that fully expands to a language name, but `\IfStrEqCase` only provides the instructions to *typeset* it.

You can use an expandable version provided by `xparse`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,dutch]{babel}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\xIfStrEqCase}{mmm}
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\said}[2][nl]{%
  \foreignlanguage
    {\xIfStrEqCase{#1}{{fr}{french}}{dutch}}
    {(\languagename) \textit{``#2''}}%
}

\begin{document}

\said{Niets}

\said[fr]{Rien}

\end{document}
```

The `\xIfStrEqCase` macro takes three argument, like `\IfStrEqCase`, but the trailing one is mandatory.

```
\xIfStrEqCase{<string>}{{<string-a>}{code-a}...}{<default code>}
```

I added to the code `(\languagename)` just for being sure what language has been selected.

[image]

Comment: I read (https://www.latex-project.org//news/2017/03/09/new-expl-ctan/) that \NewExpandableDocumentCommand is a brand new command  since earlier this month. I will try to learn how to install the new version of that package, and try your solution.

Comment: @db-inf In the meantime you can try `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand`

Comment: The `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` makes it work indeed. Thanks. I could also prove the good operation of `said`, by checking the hyphenation of a German sentence with the language set to dutch, french, english and german: `\said{\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}Andere übertragen das am besten den Geschwistern.}}` , `\said[fr]{\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}Andere übertragen das am besten den Geschwistern.}}` , `\said[en]{\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}Andere übertragen das am besten den Geschwistern.}}` and `\said[de]{\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}Andere übertragen das am besten den Geschwistern.}}`

Answer (score 1):

The other answers gave me fresh courage and new search terms. I came with an alternative solution to my problem, that allows me to define seperate language versions with ease, for each command I need.

Here is my code to define my macro commands as `\saidnl{text}`, `\saidfr{text}` etc., instead of `\said[nl]{text}`, `\said[fr]{text}` etc.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for french: OT1 encoding should not be used for French
\usepackage[english,german,french,dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\dodefcommandlang}[4]{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1#2\endcsname[1]{\foreignlanguage{#3}{#4}}%
}
\newcommand{\defcommandlang}[2]{%
    \dodefcommandlang{#1}{nl}{dutch}{#2}
    \dodefcommandlang{#1}{de}{ngerman}{#2}
    \dodefcommandlang{#1}{fr}{french}{#2}
    \dodefcommandlang{#1}{en}{english}{#2}
}
\defcommandlang{said}{\textit{,,#1''}}  %defines \saidnl, \saidde, \saidfr, \saiden
\defcommandlang{name}{\textbf{#1}}   %defines \namenl, \namede, \namefr, \nameen

\newcommand{\testphrase}{Andere übertragen das am besten den Geschwistern.
 Reële benodigdheden worden soms onverschillig veronachtzaamd.
 L’embryon de l'Organisation des Nations unies se montrait
 une casse-noisettes ambivalente.
 More than one-third of registered voters oppose the measure.}
\begin{document}
\show\saidnl
\show\saidde
\show\saidfr
\show\saiden
\show\namenl
\show\namede
\show\namefr
\show\nameen

\saidnl{\showhyphens{{\languagename} \testphrase}\testphrase}

\saidde{\showhyphens{{\languagename} \testphrase}\testphrase}

\saidfr{\showhyphens{{\languagename} \testphrase}\testphrase}

\saiden{\showhyphens{{\languagename} \testphrase}\testphrase}
\end{document}
```

In comparison with the solutions of [Andrew Swann](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358452/127384) and [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358458/127384), that answered my question to parametrize very well, this alternative has the advantage that the macro commands are 'compiled' once in the lead-in of the document, instead of on each use in the document, which will be very often. Instead of parametrizing the macro command, I now parametrize the definition of macro commands. The disadvantage of this is that I'm going to have tens of these macro commands.

Thw `\show` and `\showhyphens` commands give this result in the log file, which is exactly as it should be:

```
> \saidnl=\long macro:
#1->\foreignlanguage {dutch}{\textit {,,#1''}}.
l.25 \show\saidnl

> \saidde=\long macro:
#1->\foreignlanguage {ngerman}{\textit {,,#1''}}.
l.26 \show\saidde

> \saidfr=\long macro:
#1->\foreignlanguage {french}{\textit {,,#1''}}.
l.27 \show\saidfr

> \saiden=\long macro:
#1->\foreignlanguage {english}{\textit {,,#1''}}.
l.28 \show\saiden

> \namenl=\long macro:
#1->\foreignlanguage {dutch}{\textbf {#1}}.
l.29 \show\namenl

> \namede=\long macro:
#1->\foreignlanguage {ngerman}{\textbf {#1}}.
l.30 \show\namede

> \namefr=\long macro:
#1->\foreignlanguage {french}{\textbf {#1}}.
l.31 \show\namefr

> \nameen=\long macro:
#1->\foreignlanguage {english}{\textbf {#1}}.
l.32 \show\nameen

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 34--34
[] \T1/cmr/m/n/10 dutch An-dere über-tra-gen das am bes-ten den Ge-schwis-tern.
 Re-ële be-no-digd-he-den wor-den soms on-ver-schil-lig ver-on-acht-zaamd. L'em
bryon de l'Organisation des Na-ti-ons unies se mon-trait une casse-noisettes am
-bi-va-lente. More than one-third of re-gis-tered vo-ters op-pose the me-a-sure.

\hbox(6.8872+1.94397)x16383.99998, glue set 227.21642 []

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 36--36
[] \T1/cmr/m/n/10 ger-man An-de-re über-tra-gen das am be-sten den Ge-schwi-ste
rn. Reële be-no-digd-he-den wor-den soms on-ver-schil-lig ve-ro-nachtzaamd. L'e
mbryon de l'Organisation des Na-ti-ons unies se mon-trait une casse-noisettes a
m-bi-va-len-te. Mo-re than one-third of re-gi-ste-red vo-ters op-po-se the mea-su
-re.

\hbox(6.8872+1.94397)x16383.99998, glue set 267.23941 []

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 38--38
[] \T1/cmr/m/n/10 french An-dere über-tra-gen das am bes-ten den Ges-ch-wis-ter
n. Reële be-no-digd-he-den wor-den soms on-ver-schil-lig ve-ro-nacht-zaamd. L'e
m-bryon de l'Or-ga-ni-sa-tion des Na-tions unies se mon-trait une casse-noisett
es am-bi-va-lente. More than one-third of re-gis-te-red vo-ters op-pose the mea-
sure.

\hbox(6.8872+1.94397)x16383.99998, glue set 267.33745 []

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 40--40
[] \T1/cmr/m/n/10 en-glish An-dere über-tra-gen das am besten den Geschwis-tern
. Reële ben-odigdhe-den wor-den soms on-ver-schillig veronachtza-amd. L'embryon
 de l'Organisation des Na-tions unies se mon-trait une casse-noisettes am-biva-
lente. More than one-third of reg-is-tered vot-ers op-pose the mea-sure.

\hbox(6.8872+1.94397)x16383.99998, glue set 227.13641 []
```